# Expand Excel ComboBox on click

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

How can I configure my ComboBox control on a Visual Basic form to open when the text portion of the control is clicked, instead of only opening when the down arrow is clicked? I have been searching for a while and I can't seem to find any answers.

I have Excel 2013 and am primarily using Form Controls.

Answer (score 2):

`ComboBox1.Style = 2` was what i was looking for. I stumbled upon the answer when searching for something else.  Unfortunately it isn't enabled by default and it doesn't appear that it's an option in the properties window (at least that i could find).

Answer (score 0):

Use a "Form Control" Combobox not an ActiveX control.  The form control version by default will drop-down when you click on the data portion.